# Facebook messenger bot Webhook not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I created Facebook messenger bot in php, and its working perfectly fine when i send any message to my page. But when any other user except me (I am owner of that page) sends message to my page webhook of bot doesn't work.

Please guide.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the other user to be a tester for the Facebook app, this will give them access to the bot before it is formally approved by Facebook.

EDIT: Information regarding messenger bot submission can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/app-review

Comment: How i can ask the facebook to approve it for all users?

Comment: Edited my answer with the link.

Comment: thanks you saved my life :)